# getelementbyclass does not work

Tags: javascript, android

```
<div class="menu-kapsayici">

    <!-- BEGIN MENU BUTTON -->
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-button"><i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:#424242;"></i></a> 
    <div class="menu-button_sol">
        <a href="http://nedicen.com"><i class="fa fa-home" style="color:#424242;"></i></a>
        </div>
    <!-- END MENU BUTTON -->
</div>
```

I want to display none, (menu-button).

But getelementbyclass("menu-button") does not work for me. I am working with Android studio, webview

Here is my js code :

```
mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
              "if (typeof(document.getElementsByClassName('menu-button’)[0]) != 'undefined' && document.getElementsByClassName('menu-button’)[0] != null){  document.getElementsByClassName(‘menu-button’)[0].style.display = 'none';"+                   
                "})()");
```

Comment: Where is your Javascript code?

Comment: add your [tag:javascript] code as well.

Comment: Check the code snippet in your question document.getElementsByClassName('menu-button`’`)[0]

Comment: check the apostrophe. I copied your html and pasted it in this page and then ran your function, it caught the element. You might try consoling the function